# An android app that could send GPS data to a server

Tags: android, networking, logs, gps, web-server

I am looking for an android app that could be used to track some smartphones, for research purpose. There are apps such as Family Locator, etc. However, these apps can only show you the visual location on the map.

I want to log and record the actual GPS coordinates into a server. (perhaps sending data using AJAX? Right now, we have a server which accepts AJAX request and just log the incoming data) Is there a utility app that allows for such level of customization?

If anyone got other suggestion or other possible methods for "logging GPS coordinates from many smartphones and sending them to a server in realtime", please suggest me.

Comment: I think you might have to code it yourself. Points to ponder: how do you map received data to device? If roaming between free WiFi points, your IP address will change. What happens when there is no connection?

Comment: +0. Why would you like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest [GPS Logger for Android](http://code.mendhak.com/gpslogger/) (on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendhak.gpslogger)). It is free and open source.

It can be set to log to a custom URL. This can be set to your own server, and can contain parameters for latitude/longitude, altitude, speed, accuracy etc. It can also contain a unique serial number for each Android device, so you can tell which phone is which.

It also supports logging to an [OpenGTS](http://opengts.sourceforge.net/) server. OpenGTS is an open source project designed for tracking vehicles. So that could provide a web interface, with mapping etc.

GPS Logger has a number of options for how often to log, based on time or distance. Obviously higher frequency logging would use more data, and more battery power. It can also filter on accuracy, so it doesn't send any points if you don't have an accurate GPS position.

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I have tried sending POST and GET neither works or logs any errors in the app. I think android is stopping it because it doesnt have permission